# Is there a way to set default value in PCL-PR EXTPGM?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

Note this code:

```
DCL-S PGM1_PARM1 CHAR(10) INZ('param val ')
DCL-PR @PROGRAM1 EXTPGM('PGM1');
  PARAM1 CHAR(10);
END_PR;

@PROGRAM1(PGM1_PARM1);
```

Program will always be called with the same param. I tried adding `INZ` to parameter declaration in `DCL-PR` but compiler started to yell at me about invalid `INZ` keyword.

Is there a way to set default calling value to `DCL-PR`?

Comment: I don't think is possible in RPGLE, but you can use *OMIT and test the parameter in the called program, is the parameter address is  null, the use a default value stored in a CONST....

Comment: I look at Scott Klement (GURU) prototype manual, it's impossible. Look at [THE MANUAL](https://www.scottklement.com/presentations/Parameters%20And%20Prototypes.pdf)

Comment: @Nifriz Thank you. I am new to this. Scott Klement does provide great resources

Comment: Consider submitting an RFE to implement that feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want callers to be able to call your program without passing the parameter, add OPTIONS(*NOPASS) to the parameter in the prototype. To test whether the parameter was passed, code like this in the code for the program itself:

```
DCL-S PARAM1 CHAR(10) INZ('param val ');
DCL-PI @PROGRAM1;
  PARAM1_PASSED CHAR(10) OPTIONS(*NOPASS);
END_PI;

if %parms >= %parmnum(PARAM1_PASSED);
   PARAM1 = PARAM1_PASSED;
   ... or just ignore it if you don't care what they passed
endif;
```

Now callers can just code

```
@PROGRAM1();
```

Comment: I want something like this:

`DCL-PI @PROGRAM1;
  PARAM1_PASSED CHAR(10) INZ('param');
END_PI;`

Where the same param will get passed from the calling program.

Comment: @Ruslan The syntax you want to use is invalid. The syntax Barbara showed is how you get what you want. The effect is the same. The caller can call without parameters, and the first code in the procedure loads the default value if necessary.